# Ibm content navigator - wait service callback return value to effect isVisible() inside global action

Tags: javascript, dojo, ibm-content-navigator

I use service to get the current user AD list from serverside,

I create a new Action on the global tool bar and i am trying to hide the action if the user dose not belong to the relevant Ad,

I am using the Action isVisible() function, but i cant make the isVisible() wait until the service answer is return,  what i am doing wrong?

````
define([ "dojo/_base/declare","dojo/_base/lang", "ecm/model/Request", "ecm/model/Action","ecm/widget/dialog/AddContentItemDialog"],

function(declare,lang,

Request,Action,AddContentItemDialog) {

      return declare("OpenEntryTemplatePluginDojo.OpenMyEntryTemplateAction",[ Action ], {

           

isUserBelogToSpecificADgroup:null,

isVisible:function(repository,listType){

                 

if(!this.isUserBelogToSpecificADgroup){

Request.invokePluginService("OpenEntryTemplatePlugin","CheckIfCurrentUserHaveSpecificADgroupService",{//to know if the user is belong to the relevant AD group 

                       

requestCompleteCallback : dojo.hitch(this, function(response) {                      

if(response.success) {return response.success;}
else {
this.isUserBelogToSpecificADgroup = false;
return this.isUserBelogToSpecificADgroup ;

                             

}

                       

})

                 

});

}else{
return false;
}

           

},```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `invokePluginService()` is asynchronous and will not wait for the request to finish. Instead of this method you can use the synchronous method `invokePluginServiceSynchronous()`. This will wait for the request to finish and returns the response directly:

```
    var response = Request.invokePluginServiceSynchronous("OpenEntryTemplatePlugin",
        "CheckIfCurrentUserHaveSpecificADgroupService",{} );
```